Avoid many line breaks when formatting long lines containing binary operators with Ruff
The ruff formatter generally wraps lines with more than 88 characters (this is the default, i.e. line-length = 88).
Unfortunately, this leads to lines of pathlib paths wrapped in an unpractical fashion:
from pathlib import Path
path_save = Path().cwd().parents[1] / "some" / "folder" / "a_very_long_and_lenghtly_file_name.csv"

After applying ruff format, the second line becomes:
path_save = (
    Path().cwd().parents[1]
    / "some"
    / "folder"
    / "a_very_long_and_lenghtly_file_name.csv"
)

Desired would be only one line break:
path_save2 = (Path().cwd().parents[1] / "some" / 
"folder" / "a_very_long_and_lenghtly_file_name.csv")

Is this possible with ruff? The line-length docs don't explain at which positions line breaks are placed. I have many python files with such pathlib paths and would appreciate some sort of solution for this with few or only one line break.

From the Ruff documentation:

Like Black, the Ruff formatter does not support extensive code style configuration; however, unlike Black, it does support configuring the desired quote style, indent style, line endings, and more. (See: Configuration.)

The only way I see with Ruff is to add # fmt: skip behind the statement or surround them with # fmt: off and # fmt: on as described in this section in the Ruff docs.
This could look like this
path_save2 = (Path().cwd().parents[1] / "some" / 
"folder" / "a_very_long_and_lenghtly_file_name.csv")  # fmt: skip

or like this
# fmt: off
path_save2 = (Path().cwd().parents[1] / "some" / 
"folder" / "a_very_long_and_lenghtly_file_name.csv")
path_save3 = (Path().cwd().parents[1] / "some" / 
"folder" / "a_very_long_and_lenghtly_file_name3.csv")
# fmt: on


After reading this discussion, I decided to leave such pathlib paths without line breaks, i.e. violate rule line-too-long (E501). I just added # fmt: skip at the end to preserve readability.
